# make an array become a function that adds a give value to numbers in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6, numbers

So I was given the problem to write a function that will take a given array, add a given number to it and output a new array adding the given number to each element in the array.. so given_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ... function add(5) .... new_array (or maybe change the old array) = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] .

Here is the question:

```
// write code so that console logs print out true
//   add(addValue) should return a new arrays where addValue
//   is added to each value of original array
//   i.e. [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] > 

var e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(e.add(5) == '[6,7,8,9,10]');
```

this gives me my result but this is not the question

```
var e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var addValue = (e, Val) => e.map(add=>add+Val);

console.log(addValue(e,5));
```

Comment: Modify the `Array.prototype` object.

Comment: how would I do that in this instance? Do you mean in the answer I created? I am a novice when it comes to prototypes.

Comment: `Array.prototype.add = function add (n) { return this.map(v => v + n).join() }`

Comment: You don't need to add to the prototype. You just need to write a function. You're making it more difficult.

Comment: the problem is as well `toString`, it returns the values, concatinated by comma without brackets.

Comment: the 'this' selector. Thanks, Patrick. That helps a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

Write a function that accepts the integer that you're going to add with, and returns a new function that will perform the addition calculation when you pass it an array:

```
function add(n) {
  return function (arr) {
    return arr.map(function (el) {
      return n + el;
    });
  }
}

const add5 = add(5);
add5([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fvkw2s83/1/)**

You don't even need to create a new variable to hold the returned function:

```
add(5)([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

In an ES6 one-liner:

```
const add = (n) => (arr) => arr.map(el => n + el);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/t6gqL0dd/1/)**

And if you really wanted to add it to the `Array.prototype` (making sure you check that the new method you're proposing isn't already on the the prototype):

```
if (!(Array.prototype.add)) {
  Array.prototype.add = function (n) {
    return this.map(function (el) {
      return n + el;
     });
  }
}

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].add(5); // [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wukmf7b2/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to do this would be to invoke [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a scoped function from within `Array#add()`, using the `number` argument passed in:

```js
Array.prototype.add = function add (number) {
  return JSON.stringify(this.map(value => value + number))
}

var e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log(e.add(5) == '[6,7,8,9,10]')
```

The reason you must wrap in [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is because [`Array#toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) and [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) do not include the wrapping square brackets as in JSON encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Use prototypes

```
Array.prototype.add = function(val) {
    for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++){
         this[i] = this[i]+val;
    }
};
e.add(6);
console.log(e);
```